# how to update contentMode of UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

at initial UIImageView i have set it to

```
mCurrentImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft;
```

so if the device rotate i will change contentMode
but it had no effect. how can i fix it?

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        mCurrentImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UIDevice orientation] does not return those identifiers for orientation.  From the documentation, that message will return the following:

```
typedef enum {
   UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
} UIDeviceOrientation;
```

To change the content mode you should do something in the view controller code in the willRotate message:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        mCurrentImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    }
}
```